# Why double colon instead of dot?

Tags: c++, language-design, history

It is [rumoured](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0355/) that early C++ implementations have had dot operator for namespace access.  There is an opinion that the dot is more convenient that the modern double colon operator.

What was the reasoning behind introducing the double colon?

Comment: Off the top of my head, C++ lets you do `::symbol` to force it to look for `symbol` in the global namespace instead of the current namespace, so that's at least one thing which would look very confusing and probably introduce yet more syntactical ambiguity into the language if the dot operator was used instead.

Comment: The::horribly::ugly proliferation::of the::C++ namespace::resolution::operator everywhere is::known::as colon::cancer.

Comment: I guess it caused confusion in the semantic analyzer. Dot is also used for prefixing method names, which is a pretty similar concept and might be hard to isolate. This is a clear way to fix that.

Comment: Some hypotheses in [Why does C++ need the scope resolution operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9338217/3235496)

Comment: The horrible ugly proliferation of Mason Wheeler's senseless attacks on C has no name, because such evil must not be dignified with a name!

Comment: @Ixrec `::` was added to C++ before namespaces, so that's highly unlikely to be the motivation for it.

Comment: @Rich I wouldn't say "rumoured" -- it's categorically true, as evidenced by links in the article you link to.  The original Cfront source code (a pre-1.0 version) is available to download and can quite clearly be seen to be written to be compiled by a C++ compiler that uses `.` for scope identification, although apparently the version of the language it compiles uses `::` (see p 153 of http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_e/src/cfront.pdf - the token type `MEM` refers to `::`, and is used on p 169 as `TNAME MEM tag`, i.e. *typename* `::` *membername*).

Answer (score 15):

As [observed by Jules](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314531/why-double-colon-instead-of-dot/315250#comment665109_314531) it's a fact that early C++ implementations (CFront pre-1.0) had a dot for scope identification.

A dot was also used in *C with Classes* (1980). Indeed this is a simple snippet from *Classes: An Abstract Data Type Facility for the C Language* [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314531/why-double-colon-instead-of-dot/315250#comment665109_314531):

```
class stack {
    char    s[SIZE];  /* array of characters */
    char *  min;      /* pointer to bottom of stack */
    char *  top;      /* pointer to top of stack */
    char *  max;      /* pointer to top of allocated space */
    void    new();    /* initialization function (constructor) */
public:
    void push(char);
    char pop();
};

char stack.pop()
{
    if (top <= min) error("stack underflow");
    return *(−−top);
}
```

(the code was an example of how member functions were typically defined "elsewhere")

The `::` was one of the additions to *C with Classes* introduced to produce C++.

The reason is given by Stroustrup himself:

> In C with Classes, a dot was used to express membership of a class as well as expressing selection of a member of a particular object.
>
> This had been the cause of some minor confusion and could also be used to construct ambiguous examples. To alleviate this, `::` was introduced to mean membership of class and `.` was retained exclusively for membership of object

([*A History of C++: 1979−1991*](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) [2] page 21 - § 3.3.1)

---

1. Bjarne Stroustrup: "Classes:  An Abstract Data Type Facility for the C Language" - Bell Laboratories Computer Science Technical Report CSTR−84.
   April 1980.
2. Bjarne Stroustrup: "A History of C++: 1979−1991" - AT&T Bell Laboratories
   Murray Hill, New Jersey 07974.

Comment: Seems to me that . means membership would've been the simpler choice